# Delete rows in matrix based on two conditions

Tags: r, if-statement, matrix

I have a vector p of countries and a matrix Z of countries. Some countries in Z are not included in p. I would like an argument that has two "if's": delete countries from Z if they are not included in the rownames in p AND if they also have only NA's or 0's in Z (i.e. rowsums in Z = 0). They should only be deleted if both "if's" apply.

Here is an example of the data. In the expected output, Algeria should be deleted, since it has 0 in both the vector and the matrix.

```
p <- c(Afghanistan = 2769, Albania = 93893300, Algeria = 0, Argentina=4550430, Australia=0)
p <- as.data.frame(p)

Z <- matrix(c(0,138201.333333333,0,0,0,0,1162.33333333333,0,38.3333333333333,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,300238,0,9675,0,0,93,0,0,0), nrow = 5, ncol = 5, byrow=TRUE)
dimnames(Z) = list(c("Afghanistan","Albania","Algeria", "Argentina", "Australia"),c("Afghanistan","Albania","Algeria", "Argentina", "Australia"))
```

I attempted to do this by:
`Zsubsetted <- subset(Z, !(p == "NA" & rowSums(Z) == "0"))`

but this does not work.

Comment: Thanks both, I have added a workable example.

Comment: The `p` values are to be checked in all the column of `Z`  or only one column? Do you have matrix or dataframe in `Z` ? Check `class(Z)`. What you have shared is a dataframe.

Comment: So I guess each row is a country? Then how are your countries related to the vector `p`? Can you perhaps explain the meaning of, for example, `p[[1L]]`?

Comment: @RonakShah p is to be checked in the in the rownames of Z and Z is a matrix, now clarified with a new example. @ekoam Yes, this should be clearer with the new example. Countries are included in both p and Z, so ```p[[1L]]``` is 2769.

Comment: Why should only Algeria be deleted? Australia also has all 0's in vector and matrix. Do you need `Z[, !(p[, 1] == 0 & colSums(Z) == 0)]` ?

Comment: @RonakShah Australia does not have rowsums in Z = 0 (it has 93) so it should not be deleted. ```Z[, !(p[, 1] == 0 & colSums(Z) == 0)]``` did not work on my small example nor my real data, on the example data it only removes columns.

Comment: @JohannaH Ok...see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you were trying to use `rowSums` and `colSums` as :

```
inds <- !(rowSums(Z) == 0 & colSums(Z) == 0 & p[, 1] == 0)
Z[inds, inds]


#            Afghanistan    Albania  Argentina Australia
#Afghanistan           0 138201.333    0.00000         0
#Albania               0   1162.333   38.33333         0
#Argentina             0 300238.000 9675.00000         0
#Australia             0     93.000    0.00000         0
```

So basically drop rows where `rowSums(Z) = 0`, `p = 0` and `colSums(Z) == 0`.

Comment: Thanks, this works on my example but in my large matrix I get an error message: Error in Z[!(rowSums(Z) == 0 & p == 0), ] : 
  (subscript) logical subscript too long

Comment: For your data is `length(p)` and `nrow(Z)` equal as in your example?

Comment: No, my data is:  ```> length(p)
[1] 14
> nrow(Z)
[1] 168```